# How do I get the opposite of the if construct in Bash?

Tags: bash

`if date -d "2012010123"` runs if the date command returns a zero exit code. How do I get the opposite to occur? In other words, how can I get the if statement to run if the exit code is 1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Negate it:

```
if ! date -d "2012010123"; then
  # do something here (date returned with non-zero exit code)
fi
```

`if` takes a command pipeline (or a list thereof), and of pipelines `man bash` says this:

> The  return  status of a pipeline is the exit status of the last command[...]  If the reserved word `!`  precedes  a  pipeline,  the
> exit status of that pipeline is the logical negation of the exit status as described above.

Comment: embarrasing of me. *sigh*. this question > /dev/null

Comment: @imagineerThis It's ok; this happens at times.

Comment: @imagineerThat don't worry; the more you learn about bash, the more you realize that this question is very deep. For example, the answer talks about `help test`; but this actually has nothing to do with the test program (aka `[`, but that's another story). `!` is a bash reserved keyword which negates the return status of a pipeline, and `if` takes a pipeline, and that's just the beginning. Anyway, good question.